# Find all continuous subsets with a particular sum(+ve or -ve) where the subset can contain both positive and negative integers

Tags: c, complexity-theory

The task is to find all continuous subsets or better say subarrays with a particular sum where the subset can contain both positive and negative integers
Example:
For subset={1,-1,1,-1,1}
all those subsets resulting in sum 1 are:

```
{1}
{1,-1,1}
{1}
{1,-1,1,-1,1}
{1,-1,1}
{1}
```

which means there are 6 subsets with sum 1...i have tried it by saving previous sums but still i am only possible to do it using 2 loops..one from 0 to n and other from 0 to i-1
here is the code:

```
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      scanf("%d", &a1[i]); 
      sum[i] = a1[i] + a1[i - 1];
  }

  sum[0] = INT_MAX;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      if (a1[i] == 1 || a1[i] == -1)
      {
          count++;
      }

      if (i > 0)
      {
          if (sum[i] == 1 || sum[i] == -1)
          {
              count++;
          }

          for (j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
          {
              if ((sum[i - 1 - j] + a1[i] == 1) || (sum[i - 1 - j] + a1[i]) == -1)
              {
                  count++;
              }

              sum[i - 1 - j] += a1[i];
          }
      }
  }
```

Is there a way possible to do it in O(n) or O(nlogn) time complexity?

Comment: Could you correctly indent that code so it's readable?

Comment: There is nothing sort of python problem..but i thought that maybe we needed to use hash tables kind of stuff and maybe users have a better way of doing in python..I just want the method with complexity O(n) or O(nlogn)..language doesn't matters..and sorry for formatting problems..this is my 1st question here so had no idea..

Comment: I think that there's likely no feasible way to check `O(n^2)` possible partial sums in anything less than `O(n^2)` time...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way, because there exist N-element arrays having O(N^2) slices with a given sum. Just enumerating the output takes O(N^2).

Example: the array { +1, -1, +1, -1 ... } (length N = 2k+1) with desired sum +1.

- there are N-2 slices of length 3 summing up to +1
- there are N-4 slices of length 5 summing up to +1
- ... there are 3 slices of length N-2 summing up to +1
- there are 1 slices of length N summing up to +1

Total: 1 + 3 + ... + N-2 = 2 * (1 + 2 + ... + k) - k = k^2

Answer (score -1):

As I am still not able to comment on posts...

Are we supposed to assume for a sum of +1, sets {1, -1, 1} and {-1, 1, 1} different ?

The only way of getting at a sum of +1 by using 3 elements is by the combination of +1, +1 and -1.

Now assuming the order of the elements matter, there can at most 3! = 6 sets which can add upto +1 .

If N = 2k+1, put k = 100, N = 201, I still don't see how there are N-2 = 199 subsets of length 3 with a sum of +1 unless -1 in 2nd position and -1 is another position are in the original set are treated as different -1's

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea to post an answer instead of a comment! It seems, from the examples the OP gave, he meant "slices", *not* "distinct slices", and **certainly not** "sets" or "distinct sets" (see {1} multiple times, as well as the non-set {1, -1, 1}).

Comment: Sorry for posting a comment as an answer as I do not yet have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Yeah, that probably means you should *act so as to gain reputation points*. By breaking the rules you will probably lose reputation. Good luck.